# Localization in IOS without depending on the device language

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

Is it possible to create a localized IOS application independent from the device's language. For example in .net we set CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to the specified language, is this possible in IOS? The goal is to create a multilingual IOS application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you shouldn't do it (see [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)):

```
NSArray *langOrder = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:langOrder forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Comment: Second that. I can't see a reason to have the app ignore the device settings.

Comment: Actually I am creating a bilingual application, the use can choose his application to be in one of two languages, and I don't want to alter the device's language or to force the user to change his device's settings

Comment: @tilo, At what event do i add this? Thanks

Comment: @HassanMokdad: Why would you want to switch the language in the app ? I don't see the use case: do you really want to switch the language of just one app, but not all the others ? I wouldn't, as the user has a list of "preferred" languages in his device settings according to which the "best" language is chosen automatically.

Comment: @DurkDust, at some point your right, But that's the user's requirement. Imagine you are running a windows xp in the english language, and you browse using IE or any browser to a multilingual site, will the website open in your language or offer you many languages to choose from? it might actually do both, but can open this site in Frensh, while you computer's language is in english

Comment: @HassanMokdad: Add the two lines to `main.m` just after the `NSAutoreleasePool ...`-line

Comment: @HassanMokdad: The browser/website example is flawed as few websites do support localization which is because browsers are not required to report the languages used, but some do and do not force me to select one. You need to think normal applications: do you know one desktop application where you have the ability to select the language? Yet, when I run them and they do have German localization I get a German UI just like I expected.

Comment: Many desktop applications offer you the ability to choose language, photoshop for example

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to switch the language manually. Just follow [Apples internationalization guides](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/). Localization is pretty easy on iOS and you do not set anything to "switch" languages, iOS already chooses the correct one according to the languages you provide and the language priorities the user has set in the settings.